# Keyboard Pop up Code works but the Keypad is behind the alert box - Android

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-alertdialog, android-softkeyboard

Below is  my code I have  browsed through stack overflow and have written the below code for my popup dialog which has 2 EditText , I need to popup my SoftKeypad on alert , what  it does it pops up the keypad when i touch edittext but the keypad is behind my alertbox  .

So I have tried for forced keypad popup just below alert.show() which it does but in background and alert comes above it .

Please give a solution

Code :

```
for (int k = 0; k < mCompetitorMainList.getChildCount(); k++)
                    {
                        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) mCompetitorMainList.getChildAt(k);
                        Button btn = (Button) layout.getChildAt(0);
                        String tag = (String) btn.getTag();
                        LinearLayout dataDetail = (LinearLayout) layout.getChildAt(2);

                        if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") && btn.getText().toString().equals("OTHERS"))
                        {

                            final AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

                            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
                            final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_other_competitor_item_detail, null);
                            ImageView addImg =(ImageView)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.addCompetitorImg);
                            ImageView removeImg = (ImageView)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.removeCompetitorImg);
                            final LinearLayout competitorOtherLayout = (LinearLayout)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.competitorLayout);

                            addImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    LayoutInflater inflaterLayout = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
                                    View dialogViewLayout = inflaterLayout.inflate(R.layout.add_other_item_layout, null);
                                    EditText otherCompDesc = (EditText) dialogViewLayout.findViewById(R.id.otherCompetitorDescription);
                                    EditText otherCompQty = (EditText) dialogViewLayout.findViewById(R.id.otherCompetitorQty);

                                    otherCompDesc.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                                            if (hasFocus) {
                                                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                                                imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });

                                    otherCompQty.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                                            if (hasFocus) {
                                                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                                                imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });

                                    competitorOtherLayout.addView(dialogViewLayout);

                                }
                            });

                            removeImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {

                                    if(competitorOtherLayout.getChildCount()!=0)
                                    {
                                        competitorOtherLayout.removeViewAt(competitorOtherLayout.getChildCount()-1);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"No Other Competitor Present ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }

                                }
                            });

                            dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

                            alertDialogOther = dialogBuilder.create();
                            alertDialogOther.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
                            alertDialogOther.show();

                            //alertDialogOther.setCancelable(false);


                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Others Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            btn.setTag("no");
                        }
                        else if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
                        {
                            dataDetail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            btn.setTag("no");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dataDetail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
```

SCREENSHOT :

[image: SCREENSHOT SHOWING KEYPAD BACK OF ALERT]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void openKeyboard(){
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =
                (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
}
```

use this instead..

Comment: I get a  keyboard , but its behind the alert box , how do I bring if on front , I am using fragment ,

Comment: did you try this:  alertDialogOther.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM,
         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);

Comment: Please go through my question have added screenshot

Comment: now I see..  can you do this.. <activity
            android:name=".note.ui.activity.CreateNoteActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity android:name=".todo.activity.CreateTodoActivity"></activity> in the manifest

Comment: adjustResize, will give it the room to visible both the keyboard and the view along with keeping both them in focus.

Comment: what are note.ui.activity.CreateNoteActivity and  todo.activity.CreateTodoActivity